# Is the absolute value of the difference a kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

In particular is $$
k(x_i,x_j)=|x_i-x_j|, \quad x_i,x_j\in \mathbb{R}$$ a valid kernel?

Comment: What's the definition of a valid kernel? Can you show that this satisfies or does not satisfy that definition?

Comment: this answer outlines the basic strategy involved in finding counter-examples to proposed kernels which do not satisfy Mercer's conditions https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199620/on-the-properties-of-hyperbolic-tangent-kernel/199765#199765 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371623/checking-if-a-kernel-is-valid/371704#371704

Comment: Yes thank you, however I think that the gram matrix of this particular kernel is positive semi definite, however it doesn't seem to be a valid kernel.

Comment: What leads you to believe that it is not valid? What properties do valid kernels have & how does this not have those properties?

Comment: When you write $|\cdot|$, do you mean the absolute value or some norm? Are the $x_i$ and $x_j$ quantities vector or scalar?

Comment: For simplicity, we can assume they are scalar and that the $| \cdot |$ is the absolute value like corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed it is **not** a kernel. Consider the dataset $\mathcal D = \{0,1\}$. The gram matrix of $k(x_i,x_j)=|x_i-x_j|$ is given by
$$
K := \begin{bmatrix} 
k(x_1,x_1)& k(x_1,x_2) \\ k(x_2,x_1)&k(x_2,x_2)
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 
0& 1 \\ 1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Solving for its eigenvalues, we get:
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
-\lambda & 1 \\ 1&-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix}=0 \implies \lambda=\pm 1\not \geq 0
$$
Thus its is not positive semi definite and the kernel is **not** valid.